# Consulta que cuente puntos dentro de polígonos y sume sus valores

Tags: r

Tengo un objeto sf "primavera", que contiene puntos geográficos con una variable numérica (capturas) como atributo:

```
primavera[sample(nrow(primavera), 10), ]
  Simple feature collection with 10 features and 1 field
  geometry type:  POINT
  dimension:      XY
  bbox:           xmin: 167390 ymin: 4110610 xmax: 998509.7 ymax: 4801807
  epsg (SRID):    25830
  proj4string:    +proj=utm +zone=30 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
               capturas                     geom
  20438               3 POINT (731770.9 4388696)
  28645               0 POINT (690383.6 4604184)
  44095               9 POINT (463455.4 4518496)
  69908               1 POINT (207299.4 4127712)
  15524              24 POINT (998509.7 4704546)
  69150               5 POINT (220054.1 4110610)
  72712               1   POINT (167390 4308969)
  50861               9 POINT (439233.4 4801807)
  48422               8 POINT (433641.5 4485400)
  4756                6 POINT (784516.2 4471993)
```

Además, tengo otro objeto sf "spain" con la cuadrícula UTM de 10x10 km, que cubre toda mi área de estudio. Ambos objetos están en el mismo sistema de coordenadas (25830).

Necesito hacer una consulta geográfica/geométrica que

1. cuente el número de puntos que hay en cada polígono (cuadrícula UTM), y
2. sume los valores de la variable (capturas) correspondientes a esos puntos de cada polígono.

El resultado debe ser un objeto sf con todos los features de la cuadrícula, con dos variables añadidas: "número de puntos" y "total de capturas".  ¿Alguien puede ayudarme con esta consulta? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Este código te debería funcionar, creo que se entiende bastante bien, pero si tienes alguna duda pregunta.

```
#Añadimos a la geometria las dos columnas nuevas que queremos
spain$`total de capturas` <- 0
spain$`numero de puntos` <- 0

for(i in 1:nrow(primavera)){

  #Nos quedamos con un punto
  point <- primavera[i, ]

  #Calculamos en que cuadricula esta
  pos <- st_intersects(point$geom, spain)[[1]]

  #Actualizamo la geometria
  spain$`total de capturas`[pos] <- spain$`total de capturas`[pos] + point$captura
  spain$`numero de puntos`[pos] <- spain$`numero de puntos`[pos] + 1

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Se entiende y, efectivamente, funciona. Sin embargo, es muy lento, porque recorre el sf de los puntos que contiene casi 80.000 registros. ¿No habría opción a recorrer los elementos de la malla (polígonos) y que cuente y sume desde ahí?